# changed? method always returns TRUE with DateTime field even is wasn`t changed (using jQuery UI datetimepicker)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, datetime, datetimepicker

I have encountered strange problem - when using jQuery UI datetimepicker (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) for editing DateTime field it seems like Rails thinks that this field is always changed even if I don`t changed it. The thing is that I have validation if this field changed and it is always executed.

```
self.begin_time - self.changed_attributes["begin_time"] == 0.0 # => true
self.begin_time_changed? #=> true
```

I use text_field for displaying DateTime field and I specified Time format and initializer like this:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"
```

And even more:

```
@d.begin_time
# => Thu, 24 Nov 2011 14:00:00 MSK +04:00
@d.begin_time = "24.11.2011 14:00"
@d.begin_time_change
# => [Thu, 24 Nov 2011 14:00:00 MSK +04:00, Thu, 24 Nov 2011 14:00:00 MSK +04:00]
@d.begin_time_changed?
 => true
```

So times are equal and I don`t know how to make changed? method work properly.